EF Core | Adding a related entity | The database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually affected 0 row(s)
Unable to figure out why I am getting the following error:
{
  "title": "Server Error",
  "status": 500,
  "detail": "The database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually affected 0 row(s); data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions."
}

This is the full exception:
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=The database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually affected 0 row(s); data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.
  Source=Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL
  StackTrace:
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Update.Internal.NpgsqlModificationCommandBatch.<ThrowAggregateUpdateConcurrencyExceptionAsync>d__10.MoveNext()
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Update.Internal.NpgsqlModificationCommandBatch.<Consume>d__7.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.<ExecuteAsync>d__50.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.<ExecuteAsync>d__50.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.<ExecuteAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.<ExecuteAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.<ExecuteAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.<SaveChangesAsync>d__111.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.<SaveChangesAsync>d__115.MoveNext()
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlExecutionStrategy.<ExecuteAsync>d__7`2.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.<SaveChangesAsync>d__63.MoveNext()
   at Persistence.IKATDbContext.<SaveEntitiesAsync>d__43.MoveNext() in C:\Users\<user>\source\repos\ikat\Persistence\IKATDbContext.cs:line 54

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]
    Persistence.IKATDbContext.SaveEntitiesAsync(System.Threading.CancellationToken) in IKATDbContext.cs

I am the only one testing in the local environment. I worked according to the docs here
The code seems to be in place as well, but I am surely missing something. Note that I simplified simplified the code by removing validation and so on.
I have two Entities:
public class Tutor : Entity, IAggregateRoot
{
    public Guid Id { get; private set; }
    public string FirstName { get; private set; }
    public string LastName { get; private set; }
    public ICollection<Availability> Availabilities { get; private set; }

    public Tutor(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        this.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        this.FirstName = firstName;
        this.LastName = lastName;
        this.Availabilities = [];
    }

    public static Tutor Create(string firstName, string lastName)
    {    
        return new Tutor(firstName, lastName);
    }

    public Availability AddAvailability(DateTime startDateTime, DateTime endDateTime, bool recurring)
    {
        Availability availability = new(this.Id, startDateTime, endDateTime, recurring);
        this.Availabilities.Add(availability);
        return availability;
    }
}

And:
public class Availability : Entity
{
    public Guid Id { get; private set; }
    public Guid TutorId { get; private set; }
    public Tutor Tutor { get; private set; }
    public DateTime StartDateTime { get; private set; }
    public DateTime EndDateTime { get; private set; }
    public bool Recurring { get; private set; }

    public Availability(Guid tutorId, DateTime startDateTime, DateTime endDateTime, bool recurring)
    {
        this.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        this.TutorId = tutorId;
        this.StartDateTime = startDateTime;
        this.EndDateTime = endDateTime;
        this.Recurring = recurring;
    }
}

These are the Entity Configuration:
public class TutorEntityConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Tutor>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Tutor> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Tutors");

        builder.HasKey(t => t.Id);

        builder.Property(t => t.FirstName)
            .IsRequired();

        builder.Property(t => t.LastName)
            .IsRequired();

        builder.HasMany(t => t.Availabilities)
            .WithOne(a => a.Tutor)
            .HasForeignKey(a => a.TutorId);
    }
}

And:
public class AvailabilityEntityConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Availability>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Availability> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Availabilities");

        builder.HasKey(a => a.Id);

        builder.Property(a => a.StartDateTime)
            .IsRequired();

        builder.Property(a => a.EndDateTime)
            .IsRequired();

        builder.Property(a => a.Recurring)
            .IsRequired();

        builder.HasOne(a => a.Tutor)
            .WithMany(t => t.Availabilities)
            .HasForeignKey(a => a.TutorId)
            .IsRequired();
    }
}

These are the TutorRepository methods that I am using:
public void Update(Tutor tutor)
{
    this.context.Entry(tutor).State = EntityState.Modified;
}

public async Task<Tutor> GetTutorByIdAsync(Guid tutorId, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    return await this.context.Tutors
                             .Include(t => t.Availabilities)
                             .FirstOrDefaultAsync(t => t.Id == tutorId, cancellationToken);
}

Finally the CommandHandler:
public async Task<Guid> Handle(CreateAvailabilityCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    Tutor tutor = await this.tutorRepository.GetTutorByIdAsync(request.TutorId, cancellationToken) ?? throw new Exception("Tutor not found");
    tutor.AddAvailability(request.StartTime, request.EndTime, false);

    this.tutorRepository.Update(tutor);
    _ = await this.tutorRepository.UnitOfWork.SaveEntitiesAsync(cancellationToken);
    return tutor.Id;
}

Update
public class CreateAvailabilityCommandHandler : IRequestHandler<CreateAvailabilityCommand, Guid> {
    private readonly IKATDbContext context;

    public CreateAvailabilityCommandHandler(IKATDbContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public async Task<Guid> Handle(CreateAvailabilityCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Tutor tutor = await this.context.Tutors
                                 .Include(t => t.Availabilities)
                                 .SingleOrDefaultAsync(t => t.Id == request.TutorId, cancellationToken) ?? throw new Exception("Tutor not found");

        _ = tutor.AddAvailability(request.StartTime, request.EndTime, false);

        Console.WriteLine(context.ChangeTracker.DebugView.LongView);

        _ = await this.context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
        return tutor.Id;
    } }

This is the output. As you can see the new Availability is not found because it is not tracked by EF.
Tutor {Id: b8eab345-b775-49c8-b9d9-5aac35aa80e5} Unchanged
    Id: 'b8eab345-b775-49c8-b9d9-5aac35aa80e5' PK
    FirstName: 'goose'
    LastName: 'pen'
    Availabilities: [<not found>]

When explicitly added to the context it works. Since EF is tracking it.
Availability av = tutor.AddAvailability(request.StartTime, request.EndTime, false);

this.context.Add(av);

This is the longview:
Availability {Id: 6d920ed3-c718-4429-8039-813aa750afe3} Added
    Id: '6d920ed3-c718-4429-8039-813aa750afe3' PK
    EndDateTime: '06/25/2024 01:52:48'
    Recurring: 'False'
    StartDateTime: '06/25/2024 01:52:47'
    TutorId: 'b8eab345-b775-49c8-b9d9-5aac35aa80e5' FK
    Tutor: {Id: b8eab345-b775-49c8-b9d9-5aac35aa80e5}
Tutor {Id: b8eab345-b775-49c8-b9d9-5aac35aa80e5} Unchanged
    Id: 'b8eab345-b775-49c8-b9d9-5aac35aa80e5' PK
    FirstName: 'goose'
    LastName: 'pen'
    Availabilities: [{Id: 6d920ed3-c718-4429-8039-813aa750afe3}]


Exceptions aren't JSON strings. Log and post the actual full exception text returned by Exception.ToString() or while debugging, by clicking on the Copy Details link button in the exception popup. The full exception includes inner exceptions with more details and the call stack with the calls that led to the exception. If you have a Concurrency Exception for example, it means the data was modified by someone else in the meantime. Or that EF is misused. The "update" method is simply wrong for example: EF detects whether a tracked object has changed automatically.

EF Core doesn't need to be wrapped in single-entity CRUD classes. Such fake repositories are the root of a lot of EF problems. EF is an ORM, not a database driver. It's a far higher level abstraction that already hides the storage mechanism and strives to give the impression of working with in-memory objects. A DbContext already is a multi-entity Unit Of Work and persists changes to all the tracked entities, not just one type. A single call to SaveChanges persists all changes, essentially commiting the UoW. tutorRepository.UnitOfWork.SaveEntitiesAsync can easily delete 32 Students

Try deleting tutorRepository.Update(tutor) altogether. The DbContext already knows that only Availability was added and hence is in the Added state, while tutor is unchanged. If you let EF work properly, it will only generate an INSERT INTO TutorAvailability() with the parent tutor ID as a parameter. By calling Entry(tutor).State you force EF to generate an UPDATE on Tutor itself, which hasn't changed.

@PanagiotisKanavos The full error has been added. Also I used the repository because I have a couple domain services that made use of it. Not sure of the alternatives yet because I just started learning DDD and also because it just makes testing easier as well as because I wanted the code to rely on the abstraction instead of an implementation which I know does not make a lot of sense since it's unlikely I will be replacing EF any time soon on this practice project. But I see the point of how EF already implementing UoW and wrapping EF in repository does not make a lot of sense when DBSet does

No, DDD doesn't require CRUD classes. A domain repository isn't a single-entity CRUD class. it just makes testing easier, interfaces and abstractions do that, not single-entity CRUD classes. EF and most ORMs give you a graph of objects out of the box. The only way to raise that abstraction level is to create a domain repository performing specific operations or queries that return the graphs of multi-entity objects needed for that domain by using LINQ queries, or persist all changes at once by just calling DbContext.SaveChanges. With EF, that's a very thin layer

Long story short, you didn't post any EF code but the questions shows common bad practices so it's possible to guess what's wrong. At the very least delete the Update method altogether. If you want to start tracking detached objects either just add them to a tracked object or use DbContext.Update() and have EF start tracking them in either the Added or Modified state based on their key generation strategy and PK value. Only use DbContext.Added if you want to force an object in the Added state

The issue will almost certainly stem from how you are mapping your relationships and over-doing steps that may end up confusing EF when attempting to insert the data. EF will attempt to follow convention for things like expecting columns named "Id" or "{TEntity}Id" to be Identity Columns, which can be a bit of a conflict if you intend on setting PK values in code. (Not recommended) The Repository pattern likely isn't doing you any favours either.
Other things that can gunk up the works is over-configuring relationships. When dealing with one-to-many and such relationships, configure them from one side or the other, not both.
So for Entity configurations:
public class Tutor : Entity, IAggregateRoot
{
    public Guid Id { get; private set; }
    public string FirstName { get; private set; }
    public string LastName { get; private set; }
    public ICollection<Availability> Availabilities { get; private set; } = new [];

    private Tutor(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        this.FirstName = firstName;
        this.LastName = lastName;
    }

    protected Tutor () { }

    public static Tutor Create(string firstName, string lastName)
    {    
        return new Tutor(firstName, lastName);
    }

    public Availability AddAvailability(DateTime startDateTime, DateTime endDateTime, bool recurring)
    {
        Availability availability = Availability.Create(startDateTime, endDateTime, recurring);
        this.Availabilities.Add(availability);
        return availability;
    }
}

Something like the above is fine with factory methods and a more DDD approach to aggregate roots. What you should avoid is assigning PKs and even FKs in your code. I would extend out the static factory method rather than exposing constructors plus factory methods. You should have a protected default constructor to keep EF happy when reading data. It can use simple value constructors but will balk if you have a constructor that takes any related entities (which you may want with some aggregates)
From there simplify the entity configuration:
public class TutorEntityConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Tutor>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Tutor> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Tutors");

        builder.HasKey(t => t.Id)
             .DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        builder.Property(t => t.FirstName)
            .IsRequired();

        builder.Property(t => t.LastName)
            .IsRequired();

        builder.HasMany(t => t.Availabilities)
            .WithOne(a => a.Tutor)
            .HasForeignKey(a => a.TutorId);
    }
}

This is fine, though I would mark the Id as a DatabaseGenerated Identity where the database is set up with a default value of NewId or better, NewSequentialId assuming SQL Server. If you want to use client-side assignment (Guid.New()) then I would set it up as DatabaseGeneratedOption.None to ensure EF treats it as expecting and ID on creation.
Then in the Availability configuration remove:
    //builder.HasOne(a => a.Tutor)
    //    .WithMany(t => t.Availabilities)
    //    .HasForeignKey(a => a.TutorId)
    //    .IsRequired();

The relationship is configured on the other end, not both.
Now when it comes to saving, I really strongly recommend reconsidering adding the Repository as an abstraction for EF. In it's simplest form you want:
var tutor = await _context.Tutors
    .Include(x => x.Availabilities)
    .SingleAsync(x => x.Id == tutorId);
tutor.AddAvailability(request.StartTime, request.EndTime, false);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

That's it, simple and straight forward. EF's DbContext is already a Unit of Work and DbSet<TEntity> is already serving as a Repository. EF will wire up the FKs and navigation properties automatically. Trying to explicitly set them can gunk things up.
If you do want to use a repository, it should be for the right reasons such as centralizing common domain rules (like tenancy, authorization, and/or soft-delete etc.) or to more easily facilitate unit testing, not abstracting EF from your business logic/domain. A pattern I use for repositories is having them expose IQueryable<TEntity> rather than returning IEnumeratble<TEntity> or even TEntity. This provides many advantages such as a lightweight and easy to mock repository layer, and full flexibility to support projection, custom filtering, sorting, pagination, etc. In addition I task the repository to serve as the factory method container as well. That way a "CreateTutor" would not only create the Tutor entity, but add it to the Tutor's Dbset ready to be committed by the unit of work. (In my case, Medhime's DbContextScope UoW pattern, adapted to EF Core by Zejii.DbContext) I would absolutely avoid things like a Generic Repository pattern.

I am now working independent off the repository directly, with one single fluentAPI description of the relationship. It seems like the Availability entity is not being tracked by EF. I used the change tracker debug view. Something is wrong and it's not automatically adding the new activity to the added state.

Which availability? The one you created and added to the tutor, or one that was already associated with the tutor?  Without seeing the actual code in use, this error is most commonly caused when an entity representing existing data is fetched from a different DbContext instance than the instance that is attempting to save another entity that references it. There should be 1, and only 1 DbContext reading and updating for an operation. That or there is an entity being newed up but expected to represent an existing row.
